# How to calculate sampling weight for small sample?

Tags: sampling, survey-weights, survey-sampling

I have a very small sample size on drowning data of Bangladesh in following way

[image]

Now I want to give sampling weight for further analysis. How can I calculate sampling weight for the data? I have information of total population. I have searched in google but didn't get any concrete idea or calculation procedure.

Comment: Your sampling weight should depend on your sample design. How did you design/collect this sample?

Comment: It is a national, cross-sectional survey with 300,001 respondents interviewed between March and June 2016. It uses a complex sampling strategy based on probability-proportional-to-size (PPS) methodologies with separate urban and rural samples.

Answer (score 2):

Your data set should inherit the sampling weights from your original survey. Moreover, your 113 cases should be analyzed as a *domain* of your survey (`svy, subpop(): whatever`), keeping (in the worst case, depending on the specifics of the original design) all 300K observations in your data set. See [West, Berglund and Heeringa (2008)](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0153).

Comment: I have to work with only these 113 samples from 300k observations for specific topics. Did you recommend any articles for imbalance data cause I want to explore the effect on drowning on these groups.